# Application Hang Outlook 2016 when working in Shared Mailbox

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, microsoft-office-2016

We're using Office365 with Exchange Online, so we don't have an own Exchange Server anymore in our company.

We have a mailbox called `info` which is a [shared mailbox](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj966275(v=exchg.150).aspx). In this mailbox, we receive all orders from customers and about 15 of our sales department people are simultaneously working in this mailbox - they're categorizing the new mails, editing titles and moving the e-mails in a subfolder.

Sometimes, when someone moves a mail into the subfolder, their Outlook won't respond anymore. even if they wait 5 minutes, outlook just hangs and there's no other way to solve the issue than to kill it and restart it again.

Sometimes, when someone categorizes a mail or edits the title, other clients don't update the mails and so people start working on the same e-mail because they think it's untouched yet but actually someone is already working on it

If we delete 5000 mails from the deleted items folder of this mailbox, outlook will hang on everyones computer because it has to synchronize stuff from the microsoft servers and (i guess) edit the local data for the mailbox (in the local pst-file).

As you can see this is quite a misery. My question to you is, did anyone have experienced the same problems? What did you do to resolve this. Do we need an internal Exchangeserver so we don't have the Problem? is there something we can configure in outlook to get this working better?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a customer who is having exactly the same issue. But Microsoft wasn´t able to provide a solution until yet. The current idea is to limit the users who are working with the mailbox at the same time or upgrade the Internet Connection to a much bigger one to avoid high peaks.

Comment: @BastianW how many people are working there at the same time? Could you see how much bandwidth was used only because of outlook? How could I check this?

Comment: We have arround 12-15 users using the same mailbox at the same time. The bandwith was checked but we didn´t see any issue. Microsoft said that we might have peaks here where a longer delay could cause such issues. However the Network team wasn´t able to see such "peaks" and the overall network is arround 40% in our case. I´m not sure how you can check that but your Network admin should be able to see if the network line is overbooked (internet traffic).